# Fixed Allocator with stack - how to implement allocate and deallocate?

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocator

I've started to code FixedAllocator class that allocates memory by chunks of fixed size and works as stack, so that it works in constant time to allocate/deallocate. Actually, I'll need this class to use it with std::vector, so that I have to implement all std::allocator methods.

Everything here is for learning purposes so that - I don't need any complete implementations or headers - the real ones have a lot of code over my problem.

And I got stuck on allocate/deallocate methods - I understand that I should somehow reserve some memory pool - for example using vector, I understand that I should use static_cast to convert char type into T-type, but I don't completely understand how to rebuild this two ideas into list. Deallocate takes pointer as argument, not TNode - that's maybe the main problem.

If someone already wrote this kind of allocator - answer with code will be perfect.
Any suggestions, links and other source of knowledge are welcome. Thank you.

Here is the skeleton of code:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int nodeSize> 
class FixedAllocator : public std::allocator<T>{
private:
    static size_t Used;
    static const size_t MAX_SIZE = 100000;

struct TNode {
    TNode* next;
    char data[nodeSize];
};

TNode* head;

public:
typedef T* pointer;
typedef const T* const_pointer;
typedef T & reference;
typedef const T & const_reference;
typedef T value_type;
template <typename U> struct rebind { typedef allocator<U> other; };

FixedAllocator() {
    if (Pool.empty()) {
        Pool.resize(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(T));
        Used = 0;
    }   
}

FixedAllocator(const FixedAllocator &) {
}

template<typename U>
FixedAllocator(const FixedAllocator<U> &) {
    if (Pool.empty()) {
        Pool.resize(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(T));
        Used = 0;
    }
}

pointer address(reference x) const {
    return &x;
}

const_pointer address(const_reference x) const {
    return &x;
}

pointer allocate(size_t n, FixedAllocator<void>::const_pointer = 0) {}

void deallocate(pointer, size_t) {}

size_t max_size() const throw() {
    return MAX_SIZE - size;
}

void construct(pointer p, const_reference val) {
    new (static_cast<void*>(p)) value_type(val);
}

void destroy(pointer p) {
    p->~value_type();
}
};
```

Comment: Using a fixed sized array is far easier than using a `stack`.. `std::vector` already does its own bookkeeping. Using a stack, you'll also be doing that as the guy with fuzzy character name above points out. Don't worry about what kind of `pointer deallocate` takes.. Your only job is to `deallocate` the memory at that location.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames _'... guy with fuzzy character name above ...'_  **LOL**, feel free to check my profile to get it ;) ...

Comment: Your `rebind` returns a different allocator type, so won't work if the container unconditionally rebinds the allocator, expecting to get a compatible allocator. You might find http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/stack_alloc.html useful.